# Can object properties of double data types be retrieved using SPARQL in protege

Tags: sparql, protege4

I have an ontology in which my individuals have object properties of double datatype and I want to choose all individuals who have more than a certain amount of value. For eg. my individual has object property(hasCalories) and I want to choose all individuals who have more than 100 calories. So, can this be done by SPARQL. Please suggest some resources to know about SPARQL too.

Comment: yes, can be done in SPARQL using a FILTER

Comment: @UninformedUser can you please suggest few queries or references?

Comment: nobody can suggest queries without seeing the RDF data. In theory it will be `SELECT * WHERE { ?s <hasCalories_URI_HERE> ?o FILTER(?o > "100"^^xsd:double) }`

Comment: any SPARQL tutoials would already help you for that simple query